# Polynomials are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if they are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, why p needs to be prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The proof says we define the modulo function as the natural homomorphism,
$$ \bar\phi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$$
Then if $h \in \mathbb Z[x]$ is reducible, the identity 
$$ \bar\phi(h) = \bar\phi(fg) = \bar\phi(f) \bar\phi(g) $$
proves $h (\text{mod}\ p)$ is also reducible in $\mathbb Z_p$

**However,** this proof tells nothing about $p$ being prime. And consider
$$ \bar\phi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / 4\mathbb Z $$
is also a homomorphism, defined by
$$ z \mapsto z + 4\mathbb Z$$

Comment: $2x^2+4$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, but over $\mathbb{Z}_4$ it splits as $(2x)x$.

Comment: You're right, there's no need for $p$ to be prime.

Comment: @Randall That does not mean the statement is wrong, since from the statement, any polynomial reducible in $\mathbb Z_4$ says nothing about its irreducibility in $\mathbb Z$

Comment: @AstrickHarren  good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question of reducibility in $R[X]$ is more complicated when $R$ is not a field, so we usually restrict our attention to fields.

For example, $5x+1=(2x+1)(3x+1)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.  When $p$ is not prime, reducibility is too common to be interesting.

Comment: Does factorization in monic polynomials change something ? $\mathbb{Z}/(n)[x]$ factorizes in product of $\mathbb{Z}/(p_i^{k_i})[x]$. If $h$ is irreducible $\bmod p^k$ is it irreducible modulo $q$ for many primes $q$ ?

Comment: @reuns Even irreducibility mod $\mathbb{Z}$, which is much stronger, is not sufficient to be irreducible modulo any prime.  But I think that no polynomial is irreducible modulo a compositie integer...

Comment: That's why we should restrict to monic factorization (ask that $n$ is coprime with the leading coefficient and look at $f \equiv a_d gh \bmod n$). If $h$ is irreducible $\bmod p$ then it is irreducible modulo $q$ for many primes $q$ by Chebotarev density theorem

Comment: $x^2+1$ is irreducible modulo $4$. 

I think $f = (x-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ is irreducible  in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, reducible modulo every prime, and reducible in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for $p \ge 5$ (as $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is unramified). As $(2 | 3) = -1$, $\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}_3$ is a tower of a non-trivial unramified and ramified extension, thus $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}_3$ whence irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}/(3^k)$ for some $k$